# How to use command line completion in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

An essential convenience feature every reasonable shell provides is command / file name completion (usually triggered by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>). I miss it heavily when I use command line in Midnight Commander. Is there a way to use it (other than by hiding the panels with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just need to prepend it with <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Esc-Tab does completion, and it will even give you a tiny dropdown if you do it twice. (That being said, you probably won't get the more fancy expansion possibilities of some shells.)

Comment: This makes mc effectively unusable. You can switch panels with ctrl-u, so why can't they just leave the tab key alone? Or make panels switch with cursor right/left.

Comment: @weberjn Ctrl-u does *not* switch panels, it *swaps* panels and you are still in the same panel.

Comment: It's also `alt-tab`, or `m-tab`, whichever makes sense to you (depending on your OS). Esc is usually a reliable way when you don't have `alt` or `meta`.

Answer (score 8):

There was a fix in MC 4.8.19 which makes redefining tab work

https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3672

This config sample from the fix makes simple Tab work:

```
[main:empty-cmdline]
ChangePanel = tab
[main]
ChangePanel =
[input]
Complete = tab; alt-tab
```

Comment: put those lines into ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3664

Comment: The mentioned feature is not implemented. The task is still new. (Tested with 4.8.24)
So the solution **does not work as expected**. Just the lower assignment take precedence and tab now always invokes auto completion. You are no longer able to switch panels by keyboard anymore.

Comment: @Winand and weberjn - using `mc 4.8.19`. works a treat. thanks, excellent.

Comment: Does not work for me on 4.8.27. Do I need to do something after saving mc.keymap file?

Answer (score 7):

Alt + Tab do the autocomplete native list of MC.